# How to re-attach all event listener to elements when the page change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm a vuejs laravel developer. I should not change the design and the animations which I get from the designer.

But when I integrate `vue.js` inside the template and change the route the whole page loses all the events listeners from bootstrap and other libraries.

I know I can add:

```
$(document).on('click','.class',function(){});
```

But that will take a lot of time do, do you have any idea?

Comment: Vue won't help you in this. Using Vue, the designers should operate/edit the template that is going to be used by Vue. You should be able to add handlers directly in the template, like `@click` and such. If you aren't, you are better off doing exactly what you posted (aka event delegation).

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Vue, you should use built-in event handling:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Also, if you need animation on route change, consider using `<transition></transition>` :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

However if you want manually manage event listeners, you can do that via route guards or lifecycle hooks.